# Do not include 2nd date range in 1st date range

Tags: c#, datetime

```
   DateTime startDate1 = (DateTime)StartDate;
   DateTime endDate1 = (DateTime)EndDate;
   DayOfWeek? day = db.DayOfWeek;
   var dayCount = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == day);

   List<DateTime> dates =
   Enumerable.Range(0, (int)((EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays) + 1)
       .Select(n => StartDate.AddDays(n))
       .ToList();


    DateTime startDate1 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 01);
    DateTime endDate1 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 30);

    DateTime startDate2 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 25);
    DateTime endDate2 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 30);

    if ((startDate2 >= startDate1 && startDate2 <= endDate1) ||
        (endDate2 >= startDate1 && endDate2 <= endDate1))
```

I want to count the number DayOfWeek inside of the range startDate1 and endDate1 and exclude startDate2 and endDate2 from that range completely.

In the example ranges above, my current code return '4' Mondays when I want it to return '3'.

Let's say the endDate1 is now (2018, 12, 31) and the rest of the dates are the same, it should return a count of '8' for Monday instead of the '9'.

Basically, I want to exclude the (2) range from the count regardless if it is within/overlaps the (1) range.  How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your `if` condition is currently only about the start/end dates - I'd expect it to be comparing values with some other variable you're using for the counting. It sounds like you *have* code that's doing counting, but you haven't shown that here - please could you provide that code as well? If you can show us a [mcve], we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Please put the code in the question rather than as a comment. Ideally, provide it in the form of a [mcve] we can run immediately rather than just a snippet.

Comment: Edited, the 2nd range is not in the original code, just something I want to add.

Comment: No, I'm afraid this still isn't a [mcve] that can help us at the moment. It's code that's incomplete and won't compile. A good MCVE is something we can copy, paste, compile and run, to see the actual output you're seeing. As a hint though: a `Where` clause could easily exclude dates in a particular range.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the second range from the first range?